# UpdateMany document with array of objects in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, updates

I have a mongodb collection which looks like this

```
[
    {
        pId: "p1",
        apikey: "a2",
        count: 0
    },
    {
        pId: "p2",
        apikey: "a2",
        count: 0
    },
    {
        pId: "p2",
        apikey: "a3",
        count: 0
    }
]
```

I have an input which is array of object. I want to increment the counts.
The input objects are like below

```
[
    {
        pId: "p1",
        apikey: "a2"
    },
    {
        pId: "p2",
        apikey: "a2"
    }
]
```

this above 2 input objects matches with the first 2 objects present in the collection.
i was incrementing by iterating the input array.
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: 1) which field you want to match `pId` or `apiKey` or both? 2) what if an element no found?

Comment: on both, if not found no change should happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your input items in `$or` condition and increment `count` by 1 using `$inc`,

```
let items = [
  { pId: "p1", apikey: "a2" },
  { pId: "p2", apikey: "a2" }
];
db.collection.updateMany({ $or: items }, { $inc: { count: 1 } });
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OJTLGppzoby)

Comment: This is clean and simple `$or` works like this only which I forgot, thanks:)